# Kivy add_widget overlapping Items

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I have a layout in a `.kv` file as below. As output the `MDCards` are arranged one after the other in horizontal fashion.
But when I am trying to do the same thing using add_widget for the `MDCard`s, the cards are overlapping.
Can anyone suggest where am i going wrong?

```
    MDBoxLayout:
        pos_hint:{'x':0.02,'y':0.3}
        size_hint:{0.95,0.35}
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: True
            bar_color: [255.,255,255,1]
            bar_inactive_color: [255.,255,255,1]
            MDBoxLayout:
                adaptive_width:True
                spacing:dp(30)
                padding:dp(10)
                MDCard:
                    padding:dp(10)
                    elevation: 2
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width: 300   
                    orientation:"vertical" 
                    MDLabel:
                        text:"label1 :"  
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "label2 :"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "label3 : " 
                    MDBoxLayout:
                        spacing:dp(10)
                        padding:dp(10)
                        orientation: "horizontal"
                        MDRectangleFlatButton:
                            text:"btn1"
                        MDRectangleFlatButton:
                            text:"btn2"
                    
                MDCard:
                    padding:dp(10)
                    elevation: 2
                    size_hint_x:None
                    width: 300   
                    orientation:"vertical" 
                    MDLabel:
                        text:"label1 :"  
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "label2 :"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "label3 : " 
                    MDBoxLayout:
                        spacing:dp(10)
                        padding:dp(10)
                        orientation: "horizontal"
                        MDRectangleFlatButton:
                            text:"btn1"
                        MDRectangleFlatButton:
                            text:"btn2"


in python file with add_widget:
class MyCard(MDCard):
    label1 = StringProperty('')
    
    pass
        
        

class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        mylist=['orange','apple','grape','mango','guava','kiwi','pineapple']
        app=MDApp.get_running_app()
        self.ids.user.text="Hello " + app.USER_NAME
        for i,v in enumerate(mylist):
            customCard = MyCard(label1=v)
            self.ids.fund_ref.add_widget(customCard,i)`

.kv file

 `   MDBoxLayout:
        pos_hint:{'x':0.02,'y':0.3}
        size_hint:{0.95,0.35}
        ScrollView:
            do_scroll_x: True
            bar_color: [255.,255,255,1]
            bar_inactive_color: [255.,255,255,1]
            MDBoxLayout:
                adaptive_width:True
                spacing:dp(30)
                padding:dp(10)
                id: fund_ref
<MyCard>
    MDCard:
        padding:dp(10)
        elevation: 2
        size_hint_x:None
        width: 300   
        orientation:"vertical" 
        MDLabel:
            text:"label1 : " + root.label1
        MDLabel:
            text: "label2 :"
        MDLabel:
            text: "label3 : " 
        MDBoxLayout:
            spacing:dp(10)
            padding:dp(10)
            orientation: "horizontal"
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text:"btn1"
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text:"btn2"
```

I have tried to add pos_hint also `RelativeLayout`, but no luck in resolving.